# Want to enter negative values in input parameter in Db2 stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Want to enter negative values in input parameter in Db2 stored procedure, but it is not accepting negative values..

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Use signed type or use other boolean variable to interpret a negative sign and type your value in unsigned formation.

Comment: in CREATE PROCEDURE sysproc.SPNAME ( IN  --- which data type i need to give so that it should accept negative valuess.. )

Comment: In DB2 Development centre -- SP is not accepting negative values...I want to enter -243.55 but it is not accepting negative value when i enter...